# Download Adfm.jar for oracle 11

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jar

I"m looking for adfm.jar Oracle Containers for Java oracle 11?  Where can I download it?

Comment: Isn't part of the JDeveloper installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Containers For Java (or `OC4J`) is a proprietary framework, and part of Oracle Application Development Framework (or `Oracle ADF`).

You need to buy `Oracle ADF`. You can do it separately, or you can get it packed with Weblogic Server (Standard Edition will do).

Edit: If you need it *just for development*, then it is packed with JDeveloper 11g, too. However if you want to sell your software, you (your client) must buy a license from Oracle.